# Google Tag Manager with existing universal analytic codes

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Currently we have three UA codes on our site.

```
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(
        ['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-2'],  // Global Account
        ['_trackPageview'],
        ['Cliend._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1'],  // Client Account
        ['Cliend._trackPageview'],
        ['CoBrand._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1'],  // CoBrand Account
        ['CoBrand._trackPageview'],
        ['GroupClient._setAccount', ''],  // Group Client Account
        ['GroupClient._trackPageview']
    );
```

I need to set up Google Tag manager to use these accounts for all event tracking. For instance is an admin goes into GTM and sets up a click event, I need that click to be tracked under all three UA accounts. We cannot add them manually in GTM because the UA codes are stored in a DB and are pulled out on page load based on the client/cobrand url.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Push the UAIDs to the dataLayer and set up macros in GTM. Or create a lookup table that matches domain names with UAIDs, this could even save you the database call.

Comment: How would I push them to the datalayer? The look up table will not work for me. Thanks

Comment: Is it always three trackers, or does this depend on the domain ?

Comment: Btw. this is not Universal Analytics code although it would be a good idea to upgrade.

Comment: Its always three that come from the DB. We know which one to show by what cobrand the user is signed up with. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use macro as an ID in your tags. This macro should take GAID, for example, from dataLayer variable. This variable should be pushed to dataLayer layer by your backend before GTM container code. This way dataLayer variable will be ready before all tags are fired.